# Why Surface child compasable fill max size if i don't wrap it in an other container?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This code fills the full screen if i specify the size to be `100.dp`.

```
ComposeTheme {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(100.dp)
                .height(100.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
                .background(color = Color.Red)
        ) {

        }
    }
}
```

This code behave properly by filling the required size.

```
ComposeTheme {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
    ) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(100.dp)
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
                    .background(color = Color.Red)
            ) {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Can somebody please explain why is it happening?

Answer (score 6):

This is how `Box` works with the `propagateMinConstraints` parameter set to `true`. `Surface` is [using](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/34b9763ed29c63306853a573903732f381f7b308/compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Surface.kt#L259-L272) it under the hood.

> As an example, setting `propagateMinConstraints` to `true` can be useful when the `Box` has content on which modifiers cannot be specified directly and setting a min size on the content of the `Box` is needed. If `propagateMinConstraints` is set to `true`, the min size set on the `Box` will also be applied to the content, whereas otherwise the min size will only apply to the Box.

Therefore, the first-level `Surface` children will have min size constraints equal to the size of `Surface`.

Here is how one of the maintainers [explains](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177726827#comment8) the reasons for this decision:

> `Surface` is not really a layout. We had such issue with `FloatingActionButton` - We set min width and height on it according to the specification, but users can set larger size if they need. And now the content (icon) inside `FloatingActionButton` needs to be fill the whole size of `Surface` so we apply a ripple on it, and then ripple is clipped by the `Surface` shape. If we just set `Modifier.fillMaxSize()` it will fill the whole screen as `FloatingActionButton` has no max size specified. And there is no such which as `Modifier.fillMinSize()` as this information is not propagated by `Box` because of how the system works. So we come up with `propagateMinConstraints=true` idea, now the content inside `Surface` has to fill the min size applied on `Surface`. To be honest I am not sure the explanation is clear enough :). But yeah, if you need to have some real layout and multiple elements inside your `Surface` you need to add it manually, so add your own `Box`.

It can be overridden by `Modifier.requiredSize`, or, as you did in your second code example - by using an other container. The `Column` in your example still have size equal to the parent `Surface`.