# How to define nested Surfaces in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

The following code produces this screenshot. The code is a slightly modified version of the default app generated by Android Studio Flamingo.

What I expect from this code is for the border to appear around the Text, not around the background. I also expect the Text background to be a different color than the app background.

How should this code be modified to produce the expected result?

[image]

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BasicCodelabTheme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary) {
        val mods = Modifier.padding(24.dp).border(2.dp, Color.Cyan, RoundedCornerShape(30))
        Text(text = "Hello $name!", modifier = mods)
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    BasicCodelabTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

Comment: if you're interested in the reasons for what's going on, Surface is designed for other purposes, check out the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70957437/why-surface-child-compasable-fill-max-size-if-i-dont-wrap-it-in-an-other-contai/70957787#70957787)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by doing these 2 changes:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary, modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()) {
        val mods = Modifier.border(2.dp, Color.Cyan, RoundedCornerShape(30)).padding(24.dp)
        Text(text = "Hello $name!", modifier = mods)
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    BasicCodelabTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

- Adding `wrapContentSize()` will avoid causing this surface to occupy the entire screen;
- Change `padding` order to be applied first. Compose draws elements from top to bottom, so in this case, we'll be applying padding first and then the border will be drawn considering given `padding`;

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! That second point is kinda tricky. Not sure how one is supposed to know or learn that?

Comment: Yes, I agree. It's either check some specific passage about this or trial and error haha