# fraction in fillMaxHeight inside a column not work(android jetpack compose)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, modifier

I have a column with two buttons. at first I used maxSize for my Column and i set the vertical arrangement of my buttons to the bottom as you see in
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8fKe.png) picture.
but I wanted to raise the buttons between the center and bottom of screen(about 78% of the screen size from the top [see this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EmCe.png)) so that it would be responsive in every screen.
this is my approch :

```
 Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight(0.78f),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom

) {
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.7f),
        onClick = {}) {

        Text(text = "Sign Up")
    }

    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.7f),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.White),
        onClick = {}) {

        Text(
            text = "Sign In",
            color = Brown
        )
    }
}
```

but the problem is that it remained the same and buttons are in the bottom as well.
do you have any opinion to make what I want?

Comment: Which Composable do you have as a parent Composable of your `Column`?

Comment: It is a `Surface()` with `fillMaxSize()` @BenjyTec

Comment: Oh I deleted fillMaxSize in the Surface and It got Solved
I relly was not aware of this modifier
thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation for the behavior you observed:

If you use a `Surface`, the first child Composable will always have the same minimum size as the `Surface`. This was a decision [intentionally](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177726827#comment8) made by the Android Development Team:

> Surface is not really a layout. [...] So we come up with propagateMinConstraints=true idea, now the content inside Surface has to fill the min size applied on Surface.

There are two solutions:

**A)** Set the Surface to the exact size that you need by removing the `Modifier.fillMaxSize()`

**B)** Introduce an intermediate Composable, for example, a `Column` like this:

```
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(0.78f),  // should work now
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
        ) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

See also [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70957437/why-surface-child-compasable-fill-max-size-if-i-dont-wrap-it-in-an-other-contai) that goes more into depth.

Answer (score 0):

Solved :
Thanks to @BenjyTec
I did not notice to the parent of my column that had fillMaxSize
So I removed that and it got solved.

Comment: Glad that you were able to resolve it! Usually, having`fillMaxSize` on a parent Composable should not influence the child Composables, but with `Surface`, this is an exception. See my answer with a short explanation. If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.